# Converting datetime character string to double value of milliseconds since 1 Jan 1960

Tags: r, date-format, datetime-format, stata

I've found out how to convert a Stata datetime format from milliseconds since Jan 1960 in R from a related question (see below):

```
as.POSIXct(874022400000/1000, origin="1960-01-01")
```

I am looking to do the opposite in R: i.e. given a datetime expressed as a character string, find out how to return the datetime value as milliseconds since 01 Jan 1960 00:00:00. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use `as.numeric` to coerce the date-time back into seconds since the epoch. Since R uses 1970 as its origin, you have to additionally account for the 1960-1970 offset. Lastly, of course, take care of the seconds to milliseconds conversion.

```
> mydate = as.POSIXct(874022400000/1000, origin="1960-01-01")
> 1000 * (as.numeric(mydate) - as.numeric(as.POSIXct('1960-01-01')))
[1] 874022400000
```